# how to switch partition on a disk to boot from

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, laptop, partitioning

I partitioned my hard disk into 2 equally sized disks. On one I have windows 7 and the other is clone of the first one which I want to upgrade to windows 10. Since right now this is a clone of the previous driver, I should be able to boot my computer on this one. My question is: how do I choose the partition I want to use at the start up? My computer is a toshiba satellite laptop.

Thanks,

Comment: This would be done by modifying the windows bootloader.

Answer (score 0):

Caution:

a) Your particular source of Windows10 install may repartition the whole physical drive, so make sure you have a recovery plan.

b) Do not assume the laptop BIOS supports dual boot, but if it does:

Both your partitions currently have the same volume label and they are the same size (difficult to distinguish between) because one is a clone of the other.  Partition Magic (old software) and Acronis (newer) are examples of cloning tools that allow you to change the volume label (make them unique) and choose the boot partition. Acronis has an installable boot manager that allows you to choose a boot partition on-the-fly at boot time.

Answer (score 0):

Is your system using an EFI boot partition?  If so, you would use bcdedit to add a new configuration for the second installation.

Cloning could have caused other issues with the partition table.  Best solution would be to delete the 2nd partition and make sure you can boot to the original, then perform a full install on the 2nd partition which should automatically update the EFI bootmgr files.

Alternatively, if you're feeling brave / foolish / adventurous AND you have a recent backup of your original hard drive to restore from, you could attempt a BCD repair.  Sometimes easy, sometimes very very hard to get right depending on the depth of the issues created from cloning.

One other issue - did you notice if there was a separate EFI partition (meaning you have GPT configuration) - if not you might be on an MBR system which is handled differently.

One thing to note, when you upgrade your system to Windows 10, it's actually just installing a new OS for the most part, so unless you are lacking install media for your apps a fresh install will give you the best result.  You can create install media based on your win7 key on microsoft's site somewhere I think.

[Clean Win 10 install method from Microsoft's website:](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)

"Follow these instructions to perform a clean installation of Windows 10. If you want to upgrade to Windows 10 for free, follow the instructions in the Upgrade to Windows 10 using the tool section. If you haven’t upgraded to Windows 10 yet and perform a clean installation, you’ll need to enter a qualifying product key for Windows 7, Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 or buy a license in order to activate Windows 10. Click here for information on qualified editions.
Warning

If you format a drive partition during installation, any data on the partition will be erased. Be sure to back up any data you want to keep before you begin.
Run the media creation tool.
Select Create installation media for another PC.
Choose the language, edition, and architecture (64-bit or 32-bit) for Windows 10.
Follow the steps to create the installation media, and then select Finish when it’s done.
When you’re ready to perform a clean installation, turn on your PC, insert the DVD or USB flash drive you created, and then shut down your PC.
Restart your PC, and then press any key to boot from the DVD or USB flash drive.
If you restart your PC and your current version of Windows starts, you might have to open a boot menu or change the boot order in your PC's BIOS or UEFI settings so that your PC boots from the media. To open a boot menu or change the boot order, you'll typically need to press a combination of keys (such as F2, F12, Delete, or Esc) immediately after you turn on your PC. For instructions on changing the boot order for your PC, check the documentation that came with your PC or go to the manufacturer's website.
If changing the boot menu or order doesn't work, try again by signing in to Windows, shutting down, and then starting your PC.
On the Install Windows page, enter your language and other preferences, and then select Next.
Select Install Windows.
On the Enter the product key to activate Windows page, enter your product key. The product key should be in a purchase confirmation email if you bought Windows 10. It looks like this: PRODUCT KEY: XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX.
Note

If you’ve already successful activated Windows 10 on this PC, including if you upgraded by taking advantage of the free upgrade offer you won't need to enter a Windows 10 product key. You can skip the product key page by selecting the Skip button. Your PC will automatically activate later.
On the License terms page, if you accept the license terms, select I accept the license terms, and then select Next.
On the Which type of installation do you want? page, select Custom.
On the Where do you want to install Windows? page, select the partition that you want, select the formatting option you want to perform (if needed), and then follow the instructions.
When you've finished formatting, select Next.
Follow the rest of the setup instructions to finish installing Windows."

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what do you mean "partition to boot from".

In UEFI/GPT (or UEFI/MBR) system, the EFI System Partition is the partition to boot from. To be precise, UEFI loads a particular EFI binary on a particular EFI System Partition. Which one to load depends on the order of the UEFI boot entries (or which you choose from your UEFI boot menu). I don't know of a Windows utility to manipulate that, but in Linux we use `efibootmgr`. Also if you UEFI has a EFI shell, you should be able to manipulate there as well. Or maybe even your UEFI settings GUI.

In BIOS/MBR system, the `active` partition is the one to boot from. It can be changed in `diskpart`.

Here "boot from" means which to load the Windows Boot Manager.

As for which "os device" the Windows Boot Manager loads, it depends on the BCD Store. You can edit the BCD Store with `bcdedit`, like changing/modifying the default entry, adding extra entries and setting a timeout so you can choose which Windows to boot on the menu of the Windows Boot Manager.